# dns-323: changing UPNP update interval

Tags: nas, upnp

Is there a way to change the update interval for the UPNP server on a DNS-323?

**Note**: I know about the "refresh" button on the web management console but I'd like to automate/speed-up this process.

Comment: Minor suggestion: add a "Disk Enclosure" or similar tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've heard tell of people using [`curl`](http://curl.haxx.se/) to automate button pushing on web admin pages.  Depending on the kind of button, this could be very easy.  `curl` is a [featureful commandline file-transfer tool](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/features.html), but it can be used to activate a web control via script, cronjob, or other task scheduler.

The tutorial [Using cURL to Automate HTTP Jobs](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html) is a great resource -- section 4, Forms, may be particularly useful here.

I don't have one of these devices to play with so I can't give you specific instructions for crafting the `curl` command.  The general idea is to

- figure out what request your *web browser* sends when that refresh button is pushed, and
- get `curl` to send it instead.

It may require additional tricks to handle authentication, if the web interface requires an admin login/password.  And I'm not sure offhand if `curl` is capable of "pressing" a javascript button -- this would require more investigation.

Comment: very hackish... that would fall in my "last resort" category.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this appears to be a [common issue](http://wiki.dns323.info/information:known_issues?s=firmware#upnp_av_server_issues) - although it may be worth updating to the latest firmware (1.08 I believe)

One solution may be to hack your DNS-323 to run FFP and then install Twonky, which is supposed to be a far superior UPNP implementation, although it costs $30

Comment: The latest version of the firmware is 1.07.