# Using command line to connect to a wireless network with an http login

Tags: linux, command-line, wireless-networking, login, hotspot

I'm trying to connect to a wifi network where it hijacks all requests and redirects you to a page where you have to agree to a terms of use before it lets you connect to the actual outside world. This is a pretty common practice, and usually doesn't pose much of a problem.

However, I've got a computer running Ubuntu 9.10 server with no windowing system. How can I use the command line to agree to the terms of use? I don't have internet access on the computer to download packages via apt-get or anything like that. Sure, I can think of any number of workarounds, but I suspect there's an easy way to use wget or curl or something.

Basically, I need a command line solution for sending an HTTP POST request essentially clicking on a button. For future reference, it'd be helpful to know how to send a POST request with, say, a username and password if I ever find myself in that situation in another hotel or airport.

Comment: see [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/73503/dns-323-changing-upnp-update-interval/79269#79269) about using **curl** for a similar [command-line-webpage-button-pusher technique](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html).  i'd post it here but it'd just be a cut-n-paste job; no point in that.  if you come up with exact steps to take, post as your own answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install Lynx in advance, and then use Lynx from the command line. Lynx is a text based browser.

Alternatively, you can try using wget or curl to get www.google.com and then analyse the HTTP file returned.

Comment: **links** will do a better job than **lynx** -- it's a slightly more modern browser.  (no really.  use **links**.  check your local package manager.)

Comment: +1 links works just great. Really easy to use and does the job just fine.

Comment: I ended up using this answer this time (downloaded lynx with a separate computer and transferred the file over usb), but it's probably time I actually learn how to use curl.

Answer (score 7):

You will have to look *once* at the source of the login form to find out the names of the user and password fields. As the authentication redirect all pages, use any URL to get that source:

```
curl http://www.google.com > login.html
```

For example, you'll find:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://my-public-provider.com/agree.php">
    <input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="yes">I agree
    <input type="submit" name="push" value="Send">
</form>
```

Another way is to use (on an other computer) a proxy such as [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see what is sent "over the wire" by the browser.

Then you can build your `curl` command to post your form information:

```
curl -d "agree=yes&push=Send" http://my-public-provider.com/agree.php
```

If you do not have `curl`, it is possible to write a simple HTTP client with a language you may have on the platform (Perl, Lua, Java...).

Comment: But some web portal is pure javascript based, which means there must be a browser with JS support to access the Internet.