# Wifi authentication from captive portal with CLI

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, wifi-configuration, captive-portal

My company networks (wifi and wired)  are open, but the authentication is done with a captive portal (I usually enter my credentials in the browser).

The problem is that I have Ubuntu Server 16.04, without desktop and without internet browser to authenticate myself.

Is there a way to authenticate myself without using a browser? Like for example writing login/password in a conf file?

Thanks

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/132392/using-command-line-to-connect-to-a-wireless-network-with-an-http-login/262795

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using command line to connect to a wireless network with an http login](https://superuser.com/questions/132392/using-command-line-to-connect-to-a-wireless-network-with-an-http-login)

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is ancient, but I've had some luck with CLI browsers (w3m is my favorite, links works too). They're TUI so you can interact with a simplified version of a web page and enter/submit form data.